# How to make UI like Google Inbox app in Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, google-index

[Unscrolled Horizontal RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5WMR.png)

[Scrolled Horizontal RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cbYy.png)

I want to make Google Inbox Android app like UI in my APP, I know its
been using `RecyclerView` to achieve this. I have two questions

1. How to make First horizontal card start drawing itself after some
    left padding, coz as per hierarchy viewer RecyclerView shows &
    Scrolls from end to end then how to align first item with given left
    spacing?

2. When we are using this type of nested recycler views, how can i
    maintain adapters of horizontal recycler views so that I don't have
    to recreate it in each `onBindViewHolder()` callback to avoid
    reinflation on every scroll?